# webdriver, catching @Test(timeout = 10000)

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver

My webdriver tests are annotated with `@Test(timeout = 10000)` to force the test to end after 10000ms. This prevents my tests from hanging all night if there is an error.

However, My tests are also writing additional info to a file, and if the test times out in this way, the line is just not written to the file. Is it possible to catch this type of timeout?

```
@Test(timeout = 100000)
public void testSomething() throws Exception
{
    //Do some stuff
    //If this times out, the line below is never called.
    //print something to a file
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your need accurately. Could you save the data needed for the file and print them out in [`@After`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html) (which is always executed)?

Comment: the print to file part is writing a line for each method. If the method is not completed, the line will just be missing. I would like to write some form of error when this timeout is thrown, So i don't think the `@After` is correct here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest implementing a [JUnit `Rule`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules).
Simply extend the [`TestWatcher`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/junit/junit-4.10/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) class and override the `succeeded` method.